# How to create android number-pad keyboard without symbol

Tags: android, react-native

Nowday, in android 12, android numeric keyboard look like this
[image]

But i want a keyboard like this, that have no symbol as - or , or  .

[image]

Just like set `number-pad` on ios

[image]

How can i do this, on android, thank you guy a lots

Comment: Are you developing the app in android or react-native?, and also please specify for which language you need a help for , as per you tag you are adding react-native but asking for a help on android , or you need help in native android code to fix this and create bridging to use in react-native code

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```js
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:ems="10"
  android:inputType="number"
/>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but can i get more detail, which file can i edit this?

Comment: And how can i override "numpad" default keyboard when use this?

Comment: Isn't the question for react native, while your answer is for android

Comment: you can follow https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-edittext-with-examples

Comment: @CODEforDREAM , I don't think you are using this method , you need to design a custom keypad to take user input or restrict user from inputting the symbols

Comment: How can i do this, on android, thank you guy a lots @Nitish

Comment: ok sorry , my mistake , I saw the tag was of react-native

Comment: its ok @Nitish brother